# to display text between horizontal line in magento

Tags: css, html

I want to display "text between horizontal line", so

i am  following this link :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009654/horizontal-line-in-the-middle-of-text

but in our theme.css file, we already using ".span" & ".h2" classes.

if i use code in above link, it will apply for all the html codes which using these css classes : "span", "h2".

but i don't want that to be happen.

i am sure, this is magento topic as we are using lot of "h2" and "span" in magento, please close this question as "off topic"

give me some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use unique classes above particular `<h2>` tags say for example

```
<div class="horizontal_line">
   <h2>Text</h2>
</div>
```

then CSS class will be

```
.horizontal_line h2{
    font-size: 100px;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;    
}
```

the same way for `<span>`

```
 <div class="horizontal_line">
       <span>Content</span>
    </div> 



.horizontal_line span{
     background: #fff;
     padding: 0 20px;
     margin-top:-25px;
     display: inline-block;
     z-index: 5;
```

to get output according to you add this code

**HTML**

```
<h2><span>Test</span></h2>
```

**CSS**

```
span{
    margin:0;padding:0 10px;
    background:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
}
h2{

    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;

}
h2:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    border-top:solid 1px red;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: you are a genius, thanks a lot, if possible can you edit the solution with .span class too....

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 thanks and look at my edited answer.

Comment: is this right? = <div class="horizontal_line">
<h2><span>Test</span></h2>
</div>

Comment: how i have to replace this line : <h2><span>Test</span></h2> by one code?

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 check my edited answer